# Email sent but not received when using MSGraph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I Hit ms graph API with my Nodejs code to send the email, an email is sent with no error displayed but the email is received in the outlook sent email which I'm using
I have proper accessToken what happing behind this please help here

Code below

```
const sendNotification = async (from, message) => {
const access_token = await getAuthToken();
try {
    const response = await axios({
        url: `${GRAPH_ENDPOINT}/v1.0/users/${from}/sendMail`,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(message),
    });

    console.log("sendNotification status", response.statusText);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

};

Comment: Maybe wrong recipient?

Comment: thanks for reply, what should be the recipient

Comment: i am having same behaviour, the email is in my Sent mailbox, but it is not being delivered to the recipients mailboxes (I am sure the email addresses are correct because one of them is mine (in another tenant) and I also copy/pasted the email addresses from the user's Microsoft profile cards to ensure there were no typos). i am following the documentation here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail

Answer (score 0):

Still dealing with this?
It's likely due to the nature of the outlook account. I earlier commented that I faced this issue (now deleted). I had always used a yahoo.com account to access my outlook, entra and the other ms essentials, so I registered the app on that yahoo.com entra and then faced this same challenge (sent emails were appearing in the sent folder but was not received), so I thought I should create another outlook.com account today and register the app on that account and give it a try, it worked out very well. So if you're still facing this issue, you might want to check out the nature of your outlook account.